# Using AWS Athena to query one line from csv file in s3 to query and export list

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3

I need to select only one line, the last line from many multiple line csv files and add them to a table in aws athena, and then export them to a csv as a whole list.

I am trying to collect data from many sources and the csv files are updated weekly but I only need one line from each file. I have used the standard import to athena and it imports all lines from the selected csv's in the bucket but I need only the last line of each, so that i have the most resent data from that file.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS inventory.laptops (
  `date` string,
  `serialnum` string,
  `biosver` string,
  `machine` string,
  `manufacturer` string,
  `model` string,
  `win` string,
  `winver` string,
  `driveletter` string,
  `size` string,
  `macaddr` string,
  `domain` string,
  `ram` string,
  `processor` string,
  `users` string,
  `fullname` string,
  `location` string,
  `lastconnected` string 
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = ',',
  'quoteChar' = '"',
  'field.delim' = ','
) LOCATION 's3://my-s3-bucket/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false',"skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

I need the last line from each csv file in the s3 but I get every line using this creation query

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `CREATE TABLE` defines how to read the file. You will need to craft a `SELECT` statement to retrieve the desired line. You will need to use some identifier in the file that can indicate the last line, such as having the latest date.

For example, if the last line always has the most recent `date`, you could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM inventory.laptops
ORDER BY date
LIMIT 1
```

If there is no field that can be used to identify the last line, you might need to cheat by finding out the number of lines in the file, then skipping over all but the last line using `skip.header.line.count`.

Normally, the order of rows in a file is unimportant.

Comment: How do Incorporate this select statement with the create table statement to pull only the latest from each file into a table?

Comment: As per my answer, there is no command to retrieve the last line of a file. If it has some information you can use (eg a date, and the last line has the latest date), then you can use the query above to retrieve it. Databases do not consider the order of lines in a file important. You might need to extract the line **outside of Athena**.

Answer (score 0):

So this is impossible but you can create a lambda function to concatenate the last line of multiple csv files in a bucket directory and print to a single csv and then import it to athena for querying. I used python to solve this.

```
import logging
import boto3 ,os
import json

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
data = ''

# retrieve bucket name and file_key from the S3 event
bucket_name = os.environ['s3_bucket']
# get the object
obj_list = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket = bucket_name, Prefix = 'bucket prefix')
x = 0
for object in obj_list['Contents']:
    obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=object['Key'])
    # get lines inside the csv
    lines = obj['Body'].read().split(b'\n')
    f = 0
    for r in lines:
       f += 1
       #Reads the number of lines in the file
    b = 0
    for r in lines:
        if x < 1:
            x +=1
            if b == 0:
                header = (r.decode())
                data +=(header)
        b += 1
        if b == f-1:
            data += (r.decode())
s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key='Concat.csv', Body=data)
```